# Java method passing/ordered logic inquiry

Tags: java

Let me first make it clear that this is for an assignment.  I'm very new to programming so all guidance is greatly appreciated.  The program I have to calculate is a parking fee charge for a $2.00 minimum for 3 hrs or less, .50 cents per additional hr, and charge is capped at $10/ per 24 hr period.  Program must display most recent customer charge as well as running total.  Constants must be initialized, Math.ceil must be used, and method calculateCharges must be used to solve each cust's charge.  I get uber errors when I attempt to run this program, and you'll probably laugh when you see it, but where have I erred?  I'm not looking for the answer to be handed to me, just looking for the logic behind how to get to the correctly written program.  Please help!

```
package Parking;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class parking 
    {
    private static final double THREE_HOURS = 2.00;
    private static final double PER_HOUR_COST = .50;
    private static final double WHOLE_DAY_COST = 10.00;

    public static void main (String [] args)
        {
        double hoursParked = 0;
        double cumulativeCharges = 0;
        double storage1 = 0;
        double storage2 = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.print("\nThis program displays the charge for the most recent customer");
            System.out.print(" as well as the running total of yesterday's receipts\n");

            do
            { System.out.printf("Enter an number between 1-24 for hours parked in garage or -1 to quit:");

              hoursParked = input.nextDouble ();
            }
            while((hoursParked > 0)&&(hoursParked <= 24)&&(hoursParked != -1));

                if( hoursParked <= 3)
                    System.out.printf("Most recent customer's charge was: %.2f\n" , THREE_HOURS);
                    storage1 += THREE_HOURS;

                 if(hoursParked >= 18.01)
                     System.out.printf("Most recent customer's charge was:%.2f\n" , WHOLE_DAY_COST);
                     storage2 += WHOLE_DAY_COST;

                 double result = calculateCharges(hoursParked * PER_HOUR_COST);
                    System.out.printf("Most recent customer charge was:%.2f\n" , result);

                 cumulativeCharges = storage1 + storage2;
                 System.out.printf("Running total of yesterday's receipts is:%.2f\n" , cumulativeCharges);

        } // end main

        public static double calculateCharges (double hoursParked)
        {
            Math.ceil(hoursParked);

            double total = hoursParked * PER_HOUR_COST;

            return total;
        } // end method calculateCharges
    } // end class parking
```

Comment: What do you mean by "uber errors"? Are they compiler errors? Does the program compile but throw an exception when it runs? Does it run but print out unexpected output? You need to say exactly what errors you are seeing. Error messages usually give you a good indication of where the problem is.

Comment: This is just the tip of the iceberg that I see when I attempt to run the program:Usage: javaw [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  javaw [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -server   to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot   is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.
                  
    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>

Comment: That doesn't help, because we don't know what you're doing to generate those errors.

Comment: @ Jeremy D. How do I set a sentinal controlled loop correctly in a do...while statement? Obviously how I set it was wrong. And so you're saying double result = calculate Charges(hoursParked) is correct.  I can't lie and its painfully obvious that this language (at one month in) looks very foreign to me.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show exactly what command line you are using and the output? The tip of the iceberg is that you are passing the wrong options to javaw, but unless you show us the full command we won't be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

In your while condition, the third condition is useless because if the value is positive, that necessarily means it is different than -1.

In your function you want to calculate the cost of parking time but you give as parameter a cost instead of a number of hours when you call your function. Is that normal? With that you will calculate the cost of the cost instead of the cost corresponding to a number of hours.

```
public static double calculateCharges (double hoursParked)
```

and

```
double result = calculateCharges(hoursParked * PER_HOUR_COST);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things here.

Your while condition is checked at the end of the do loop, it is what allows you to break after reading hoursParked.  Thus, the only way you are going to reach the code outside of the do loop (after the while), is if hoursParked is -1.

Secondly, when you do not have braces for your if conditions, you are only executing the first line after it, aka. the System.out.print's.  Therefore, your first if condition will execute (printing the string), then storing 2.00 in storage1. Similarly, the second if condition will execute (printing the string), then storing 10.00 in storage2.

Because hoursParked is always -1, you are passing in (-1 * .5) to calculateCharges.  You are not storing the result of Math.ceil() so it effectively does nothing.  You are then returning (-.5 * .5) = -.25.

cumulativeCharges is just adding 2 + 10 in every case.

Suggestions - make sure you are encapsulating the code you want to execute inside the do loop, and only break after you have done your calculations on hoursParked.